# Software (other than iTunes) to stream music from an iTunes server

Tags: itunes, mp3, streaming, music

I have purchased a networked hard drive (ReadyNAS) that I have put all of my MP3s onto. This NAS has a built-in iTunes streaming server.

What media applications, other than iTunes, can I use to stream music from an iTunes server (I don't really want to use iTunes)?

Answer (score 0):

If it streams to iTunes it's probably DAAP protocol. Rhythmbox/Amarok/Any player with daap support should be able to connect to it.